# How to Import from nth row from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I have csv file with data shown below, I want to import from row 8 & rest as row 8 contains column header with separator ';'

8th row data: Variable Code;country;year;perc;...

```
Variable Name;.;.;.;Fiscal income  | individuals | Average | Adults | constant 2015 local currency;Fiscal income  
Variable Category;.;.;.;Income inequality;Income inequality;Income inequality;Income inequality;Income inequality;
Variable Description;.;.;.;Average Fiscal income within a given percentile group. Fiscal income is defined as the
Variable Decomposition;.;.;.;[Fiscal income ]=[Fiscal labour income ]+[Fiscal capital income ];[Fiscal income ]=[F
Variable Unit;.;.;.;"USD; United States dollar";"USD; United States dollar";"USD; United States dollar";"USD; Unit
Methodological Notes;.;.;.;Excludes capital gains.;Excludes capital gains.;Fiscal income rescaled to match the mac
Sources;.;.;.;Atkinson, Anthony B. (2015). Top Incomes in Central Africa: Historical Evidence. The World Wealth an
Variable Code;country;year;perc;afiinc992i;afiinc992t;aptinc992i;aptinc992t;mfiinc999i;mptinc999i;ofiinc992i;sfiin
;ZW;1984;pall;1047.54459798;1600.48352917;1596.60595703;2439.36300347;4587650564.28;6992227570.87;;;
;ZW;1984;p99p100;17178.3969917;;26182.3038581;;;;;;
;ZW;1984;p99.5p100;21944.3422231;;33446.2776899;;;;;;
;ZW;1984;p99.5p99.9;18435.6621847;;28098.5536297;;;;;0.0703958573423;0.0703958573423
;ZW;1984;p99.75p100;27211.2576341;;41473.8008488;;;;;;
;ZW;1984;p99.95p100;44009.8265642;;67077.1930817;;;;;;
;ZW;1984;p99.9p100;35979.2715133;;54837.4926839;;;;;;
;ZW;1984;p99.9p99.95;27947.7590762;;42596.3330944;;;;;0.0133386846805;0.0133386846805
;ZW;1984;p99p99.5;12412.4517603;;18918.3300262;;;;;0.0592454023724;0.0592454023724
;ZW;1984;p99;;;;;;;17178.3969281;0.163987109323;0.163987109323
```

Comment: try np.genfromtxt, pandas, csv module, etc

Comment: @cbll, data = pd.read_csv(sourcePath, skiprows=7,sep=';')

Answer (score 1):

```
data = pd.read_csv(sourcePath,dtype=object,skiprows=7,sep=';')
```